# Hi, could someone please tell me what Xiaokuluze might mean in mandarin? Is this a model of car?

Tags: translation

Im wondering what Xiaokuluze means in mandarin, is it a model of car??

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

酷(ku)路(lu)泽(ze) is the name of Toyota Land Cruiser. 小(xiao) means small, maybe there is a car similar to Land Cruiser but smaller. Compact Cruiser?